# How to send multiple values in a loadJson?

Tags: javascript, json, server, client

Using a loadJSON on the client I need to send the `playerid` and `itemid` to the server but I only know how to send them individually, how do I use both of them in the loadJSON so I can get the information from `let itemid=req.params.itemid` like in `let playerid=req.params.playerid`

Client:

```
itemid = 1;

loadJSON('/AddItem/'+playerid,(dataReceived)=>{

    for (let j = 0; j < arrPanels[currPanel].slots.length; j++) {
        if (arrPanels[currPanel].slots[j].item == dataReceived[0].itm_id) {

            arrPanels[currPanel].slots[j].itemQuantity = dataReceived[j].plitm_quantity

        }
    }
});
```

Server:

```
app.get('/AddItem/:playerid',(req,res)=>{

    let playerid=req.params.playerid;
    let itemid=req.params.item;

    let sql ="SELECT itm_id FROM playeritems WHERE pl_id='"+playerid+"' AND itm_id='" +itemid+ "'";

    db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        if(result.length<1){

            let sql = "INSERT INTO playeritems (pl_id, itm_id, plitm_quantity) VALUES ('"+playerid+"','"+itemid+"', '"+add1+"')"

            db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

            let sql ="SELECT * FROM playeritems WHERE pl_id='"+playerid+"' AND itm_id='" +itemid+ "' AND plitm_quantity > 0";

                db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                
                    res.send(result);
                });
            });

        }else{
            let sql ="UPDATE playeritems SET plitm_quantity = plitm_quantity + 1 WHERE pl_id='" +playerid+ "' AND itm_id='" +itemid+ "'"  

            db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
                if(err) throw err;

                let sql ="SELECT * FROM playeritems WHERE pl_id='"+playerid+"' AND itm_id='" +itemid+ "' AND plitm_quantity > 0";

                db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                
                    res.send(result);
                });

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `loadJSON()`?

Comment: You need to define a route like `/AddItem/:playerid/:itemid`

Comment: @Barmar and what do I do in the client?

Comment: `'/AddItem/'+playerid+'/'+itemid`

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot, it's working fine!